# How to change the background color of df.plot() in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to specify the color of the area *surrounding* a plot created using the `df.plot()` in Pandas/Python.

Using `.set_facecolor` as in the code below only changes the area *inside* the axes (see image), I want to change the color outside too.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(components, columns=['PC1','PC2']
df.plot('PC1','PC2','scatter').set_facecolor('green')
```

Replacing the last line with these two lines produces the same graph.

```py
ax = df.plot('PC1','PC2','scatter')
ax.set_facecolor('green')
```

[image]
[setfacecolor example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgAt3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `fig.set_facecolor`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot('PC1','PC2','scatter', ax=ax).set_facecolor('green')
fig.set_facecolor('green')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to avoid adding the `fig,ax` line?

Comment: Your code and `plt.gcf().set_facecolor('green')`